# Keep the encryption value of the encryption result using RSA algorithm

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I'm using RSA algorithm to encrypt/decrypt string with pair key. This pair key is fixed. After encrypting many times, the result return is different. With my biz, I want to keep the value of the encryption result after encrypting many times. How I should do that?

I'm using `javax.crypto` of java sdk.

Comment: Show the code that does this, there are a number of questions that immediately come to mind, and rather than play a game of 20 questions it's better to just show your code. Also, why do you RSA-encrypt more than once?

Answer (score 0):

That's just not how it works. If it would be the same, that's rather insecure. PKI (Public key crypto) is incredibly slow and inefficient. Hence, you don't actually encrypt the data with it. Instead, you generate a random key, you use a symmetric algorithm like AES to encrypt the data, and then you encrypt *the randomly generated key* with your RSA algorithm.

Presumably (you included no details at all in your question), you're using a library that takes care of all this for you. As well it should, it is incredibly easy to make a mistake that results in data that *looks* encrypted but can fairly easily be disassembled; if not outright decrypted, at least a lot of info can be trivially gleaned from it. Even if you hand-wrote all the low-level stuff for PKI, it's still far less secure to re-use keys like this. All other involved parties assume those encryped symmetric keys are fleeting. They are used for this 'session' and not reused. Various cryptographic primitives do not do well when things are reused.

Comment: So don't have any way to keep the value of the encryption result after encrypting many times?

Comment: Not without significant negative impact to security, no.